# Unable to set JAVA_HOME to jdk

Tags: java, environment-variables, jdk, android-studio

I am trying to run android studio on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But when I run the studio.sh script, i am asked to set JAVA_HOME to jdk from jre. Despite the fact that I have set
`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64`
from the environment file in etc and added my own script in profile.d, the error is still there. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance

PS: When I use `echo $JAVA_HOME`, it does show the value that I have set.

Edit: Output for `ls /usr/lib/jvm`:

```
java-1.5.0-gcj*            java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64*  java-7-openjdk-amd64
java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64  java-6-openjdk-amd64      java-gcj*
java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64*  java-6-openjdk-common     java-gcj-4.8*
```

asteriks (*) are cyan in color and rest are blue. Sorry coundn't upload screenshot.

Edit 2: Output for update-`alternatives --display java`

```
java - auto mode
link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/bin/gij-4.8 - priority 1048
slave java.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gij-4.8.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1061
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1071
slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java'.
```

I have tried setting JAVA_HOME to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin`. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Where is your java installed? Please add output of `ls /usr/lib/jvm` to your question.

Comment: Please also add output of `update-alternatives --display java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your java is not `jdk` but only `jre`. And it is installed a weird way.

Install java a normal way by

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

and set

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-7-jdk-amd64/
```

Comment: Check the update.